# Error trying to change sql database folder on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, today-extension

I'm trying to change my database folder to share my app database with my today widget for all the old versions of my app. On didfinishlaunchingwithoptions I call "changeDatabase" function :

```
    -(void)changeDatabase
    {
        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"123456.sqlite"];

        NSString *destinationPath =[[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.123456.CdCTodayExtensionSharingDefaults"] absoluteString] stringByAppendingString:@"123456.sqlite"];

        NSError *err;

        if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
        {
            [fm copyItemAtPath: filePath toPath: destinationPath error: &err];
            [fm removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];
        }

        NSLog(@"ERROR %@",err);

        NSLog(@"%@*****%@",filePath,destinationPath);
}
```

but I can't do it, and the error log is this :

```
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" 
 UserInfo=0x1700fd480 
 {
    NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/03504063-CB59-417E-B5E8-FC6CB9DBF3B2/Documents/123456.sqlite,
     NSUserStringVariant=(Copy), 
     NSDestinationFilePath=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/DB5F1F23-114B-4651-B206-D53EAA0A2CB5/123456.sqlite,
     NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/03504063-CB59-417E-B5E8-FC6CB9DBF3B2/Documents/123456.sqlite, 
     NSUnderlyingError=0x1702408a0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"
    }

 /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/03504063-CB59-417E-B5E8-FC6CB9DBF3B2/Documents/123456.sqlite*****file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/DB5F1F23-114B-4651-B206-D53EAA0A2CB5/123456.sqlite
```

Its a simple thing but I don't know what is the problem. Thanks to all the SO community.

Comment: It's telling you that `123456.sqlite` doesn't exist in the documents directory. Are you sure it's there?

Comment: Yes, the database is in this folder. I check it.

Comment: @KurroCantos is this solved. please let us know.